# Why doesn't a line draw after instantiating it on a thread other than the renderer thread?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm making a 2D game with OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android, as an excuse to learn a bunch of things. I'm drawing many lines to make a grid, but setting everything up takes time and I want to render a loading screen while I set up the objects that will be drawn later.

While trying to tackle this issue, I'm facing a problem that I can't understand so my question is why am I seeing this behavior.

**The code:**

This is the class whose instances will represent each line:

This is just a slightly modified example I found on the web. There's a call to Thread.sleep that's only meant to increase the time it takes to create it, so that I can show the problem I'm facing.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import android.opengl.GLES20;

public class LineExample {

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "   gl_Position = vPosition;" +
                "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);" +
                "}";

    private int mProgram;
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer bb;



    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // bytes per vertex
    private float lineCoords[] = new float[2*COORDS_PER_VERTEX];
    private int vertexCount = lineCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;

    public LineExample(float[] lineCoords) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.lineCoords = lineCoords;

        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
        // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                lineCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(lineCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                                                   vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                                                     fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables

    }

    public void draw() {

        // Add program to OpenGL environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                     GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                     vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // Draw
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, vertexCount);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }

    private static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }

}
```

Here's the renderer:

```
public class MyRenderer2 implements Renderer {

    LineExample currentLineToRender = null;

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        if (currentLineToRender!=null){
            currentLineToRender.draw();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        //initializeLines();
        initializeLinesSameThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    private void initializeLines(){
        float[] waitingLineVerts = {-0.5f,0.0f , 0.5f,0.0f};
        currentLineToRender = new LineExample(waitingLineVerts);
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                float[] doneLineVerts = {0.0f,-0.5f , 0.0f,0.5f};
                currentLineToRender = new LineExample(doneLineVerts);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void initializeLinesSameThread(){
        float[] waitingLineVerts = {-0.5f,0.0f , 0.5f,0.0f};
        currentLineToRender = new LineExample(waitingLineVerts);
        float[] doneLineVerts = {0.0f,-0.5f , 0.0f,0.5f};
        currentLineToRender = new LineExample(doneLineVerts);
    }

}
```

The goal is to see the an horizontal line for 5 seconds (analogous to a loading screen) then see a vertical line (analogous to the actual game grid). However, with this code I get a dark screen for ~10 seconds and then the second line is drawn.

I figured that the thread is busy with the initialization code so it's not drawing the first line, so to allow it to get to the **onDrawFrame** method and draw the first line, I decided to call the initialization of the second line on another thread (by calling **initializeLines()** instead of **initializeLinesSameThread()** on **onSurfaceCreated**), but by doing that, I only see the first line and I never get to see the second.

My guess is that some things that are done in the other thread aren't accessible by the renderer thread when the line's draw method is called.

My question is why is this happening?

(and I'd be grateful if you could give me a suggestion on how to achieve what I want to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should do all OpenGL calls in the same thread. Otherwise you will get unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I feel I need to explain a few things: 1. The reason why I'm calling the 2nd line in another thread is to allow the renderer's onDrawFrame() to draw the first line (analogous to a loading screen) while I load all actual game assets. 2. I explained the Thread.sleep is only there to show the problem I'm facing, otherwise I'd never see the 1st line even if this worked as I'd expect. 3. vertexCount is always the same (2), it's a function of COORDS_PER_VERTEX and lineCoors' length. This could be more clear but I chose to leave it as it was in the tutorial I got it from.

Comment: 4. The algorithm is supposed to assign the first line's instance in the renderer's currentLineToRender variable, then assign the second line to that same variable. If enough time passes between the two and if initializing the second line in another thread was possible, the first line should be drawn in the screen while that's happening. Otherwise I don't see how to draw a loading screen while I'm initializing all game assets.

Comment: sorry I overread the part with the thread sleep and you're right about the vertexCount stuff. But anyway you cannot use another thread to initialize the second line. OpenGL cannot be used in another thread. So all gl calls have to be done in the renderer thread.

Comment: btw isn't it easier to do the loading screen without opengl. Perhaps something like [this](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/)?

Comment: By making further tests, I realized that the returned values for the 2nd line's shaders and program were always 0 when executed from another thread, so when the renderer thread attempted to draw it, it couldn't. The correct answer seems to be that all OpenGL calls have to be made in the renderer's thread. I'm accepting your answer since you pointed me in the right direction but you might want to edit it. Also, thanks for the suggestion for an alternative!